# How do I save a geodatabase from the internet that has ftp?

Tags: file-geodatabase, download, ftp

How do you save the geodatabase on the ftp ?

It only has the name of the geodatabase with the extension .gdb on it and when I right click on it and it just says download...

I have never done it before.

Edit : I am attaching this screenshot so you will know what it looks like

[image]

Comment: What happens if you do indeed download it? It's possible that it is a zip file, but the extension is not shown or it was removed. If not, the file geodatabase is just a folder with files in it as far as an FTP server is concerned, so you should see a folder listing if that's the case.

Comment: File geodatabase is **not** a file -- it is a *directory* and composed of files.  To transfer it you need to use zip, tar, or some other archive format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dedicated FTP client ([Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), for example), and not your web browser (your screenshot looks like you're using a browser). Connecting to the FTP server with an actual FTP program will allow you to download the entire folder structure. As everyone points out in the comments, a geodatabase is just a folder with files inside, if you grab the entire .gdb folder from the FTP server, you'll see it in ArcGIS as a geodatabase.